# load function loads page but can't do anything with the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So I load this:

```
 $('#categories').load("/Category/GetCats");
```

from this controller

```
    public ActionResult GetCats()
    {
        var model = db.Cats
            .Where(c => c.user_id == 5);

        //var query = from c in db.Cats where c.user_id == 4 orderby c.catId select c;
        //var i = query.Count();
        //var results = query;

        return PartialView("_PartialGetCats", model);
    }
```

to render this view

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {

    <tr>

        <td data-id="@item.catId">@item.item_name</td>

    </tr>

   }
```

The categories show but this function

```
     $('#categories tr').on("click", function () {
                var requestpage = "/Item/Partial?id=" + $(this).data("id");
                alert(requestpage);
                $.get(requestpage, function (result) {
                    $("#results").html(result);
                });
```

or any other jquery functions do not recognize the `$('#categories tr)`. It will however recognize `$('#categories')`. I tested by removing the `load()` and hardocding this

```
   $('#categories').html('<tr data-id="5"><td>new data</td></tr>');
```

and it works. Whats going on?

EDIT: full Index.cshtml view

```
   @{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}



 <div id="categories">
 </div>

 <div id="results">
 </div>
 <div id="descrip">

 </div>
```

Comment: You should use event delegation. Change it to `$('#categories').on("click", "tr", function () {`

Comment: Where is #categories ?

Comment: @PKKG sorry thought you said what

Comment: can u show the complete view ?

Comment: #categories is in Index.cshtml

Comment: added view to question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: Did you wrap the js in Document.ready ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use event delegation or use the callback for jQuery `.load()`.

jQuery `.load()` callback method:

Wait to wire up the click event until the HTML is in the DOM, this is why when you hardcode the HTML in via the `.html()` function it works, because the `on("click"` can find the elements to bind to. Instead do this:

```
$('#categories').load("/Category/GetCats", function () {
    $('#categories tr').on("click", function () {
        var requestpage = "/Item/Partial?id=" + $(this).data("id");
        alert(requestpage);
        $.get(requestpage, function (result) {
            $("#results").html(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Event delegation method:

This allows you to bind events to content that exists or may exist in the future, like this:

```
$('#categories').load("/Category/GetCats");

$("#categories").on("click", "tr", function(){
    var requestpage = "/Item/Partial?id=" + $(this).data("id");
    alert(requestpage);
    $.get(requestpage, function (result) {
        $("#results").html(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: it recognizes the row but is not grabbing the id

Comment: Sounds like you need to post a new question about your model. If you feel this answer helped your original question about the jQuery `.load()` function, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks now that its recognizing rows I'm sure I can figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `on` method a bit differently. Instead of the selector `$('#categories tr')`, you should use

```
$('#categories').on("click", "tr", function () { });
```

The reasons is, the `on` method gets hooked on whatever is in the selector and then captures the `click` event. Since, when you run this code, there is no `tr` in `#categories`, the `on` method never gets hooked. But if you use the method I stated, the `on` will get hooked on `#categories` and would work for every `click` on any `tr` in `#categories`

Comment: with both ways I'm getting an `undefined` for the id

Comment: @PKKG I did. BUt at least its recognizing the `<tr>` now